# Free-before-overwriting code, how to fix memory leaks?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks, malloc, dynamic-allocation

I have a function that uses two copies of a 2D array and does some mathematical operations on them, but I can free before overwriting. The code is something like this:

```
int **function(int **A)
{
    int **B = (int **)malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
         B[i] = (int *)malloc(M*sizeof(int));
    //the operations i need to do

   return B;
}
```

And in main the call is like this(A in int **):

```
A = function(A);
```

Is there a way to get rid of leaks without changing the code too much ?

Comment: Inside `function()` deep-free `A` before returning.

Comment: What do you mean ?

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        free(A[i]);

    free(A);
?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: I still get memory leaks if i do this.

Comment: "*still get memory leaks*": Those then due to something else, you do not show us. How do you detect the leak(s)?

Comment: BTW and unrelated, those casts to `malloc()` & Friends are useless in C.

Comment: Does the code inside `function` (that you do not show us) by any means does `A[...]  = ...`  or `A = ...`?

Comment: i use valrind --leak-check=yes

Comment: Dare showing the Valgrind logs and the liens of code those logs refer to?

Comment: Use Valgrind's option `--track-origins=yes` as well.

Comment: It is a general question, but yes, i may have something like A[i][j] += B[j][i] or something. Is this the problem ?

Comment: `A[x][y] = ....` is ok, as it modifies the array's elements. `A = ...` and `A[x] = ...` aren't, but change the pointers you allocated to create this "jagged" array.